# Status of mingw64 Python cross-build

Tags: python, python-3.x, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

There is a ton of patches for cross-building Python in python's bug tracker. As far as I understand, these track the latest development:

- [issue18654](http://bugs.python.org/issue18654) - modernize mingw&cygwin compiler classes (new)
- [issue17605](http://bugs.python.org/issue17605) - mingw-meta: build interpreter core
- [issue18653](http://bugs.python.org/issue18653) - mingw-meta: build core modules
- [issue19245](http://bugs.python.org/issue19245) - mingw-meta: install (new)

However, most of those is targetting Python 3.4, which is already out. I would like to finally get rid of awkwared Windows shell for building code with embedded python. Has someone any hints?